# Linux : Focus on terminal window is lost when calling feh image viewer

Tags: linux, keyboard, raspbian

Once my desktop (Raspbian) is loaded, I have a script launched in a terminal window that loads a fullscreen image in feh image viewer. Then, my script waits for user entry through keyboard (barcode scanner here).

The user must only see the image viewer on the screen, never the terminal nor any other application.

The fact is when feh has its first image loaded, I lost the focus on the terminal window (that is behind feh). But I absolutely have to get the keyboard inputs to let my script running in background (it loads other images, depending on what it's scanned).

Do you have an idea on how to get the keyboard inputs in my terminal window that is located behind my image viewer (feh) window ?

Actually my script waits for user input like that :

```
echo "Please scan your barcode:"
read string // reads user inputs if window is in foreground only
result=`node node.js $string`
echo $result
```